# How to host privacy policy document web page for a mobile app

Tags: c#, azure, mobile, azure-web-app-service

I have a mobile app that requires legal policies document. My tech stack includes building mobile app in ionic angular and Web API , hosted in Azure.

The ask is to provide url for legal policies, so where should I host these web pages? Should I create a web app on the same app service plan just to host these privacy policies documents ? or is there any other means. Currently the app service plan hosts the Web API.

Thanks

Comment: Look at Static website hosting in Azure Storage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website

Answer (score 1):

The more commonly free ones that I know of are these 3

- Github ([Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/))
- Bitbucket ([Static website](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/publishing-a-website-on-bitbucket-cloud/))
- Gitlab ([Gitlab Pages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/))